# SQLite Database and Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have been given an SQLite file to exam using python. I have imported the SQLite module and attempted to connect to the database but I'm not having any luck. I am wondering if I have to actually open the file up as "r"  as well as connecting to it? please see below; ie f = open("History.sqlite","r+")

```
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect("history.sqlite")
    curs = conn.cursor()
    results = curs.execute ("Select * From History.sqlite;")
```

I keep getting this message when I go to run results:

> Operational Error: no such table: History.sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SQLite file is a single data file that can contain one or more *tables* of data.  You appear to be trying to `SELECT` from the *filename* instead of the name of one of the tables inside the file.

To learn what tables are in your database you can use any of these techniques:

1. Download and use the command line tool *sqlite3*.
2. Download any one of a number of GUI tools for looking at SQLite files.
3. Write a `SELECT` statement against the special table `sqlite_master` to list the tables.